# Spring Boot cannot find properties file declared in external directory

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

I'm having an issue getting a Spring boot application to pick up a properties file after deploying.

My goal is to have a configuration folder external to the Jar so I have excluded the configuration in the Maven build:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*.*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and I have an build assembly configured as:

```
<assembly>
    <id>bin</id> 
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <outputDirectory>config</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/bin</directory>
            <outputDirectory>bin</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
          <directory>target</directory>
          <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
         <includes>
           <include>jarname*.jar</include>
         </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Which create my folder structure as expected with the configuration files in the config folder and the jar in a lib folder

[image]

Now when I run the jar from the lib directory, I get an error advising it can't find the properties, which I would expect as the configuration files are excluded from the Spring Boot build:

`java -jar jarname.jar`

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.package.application.ApplicationMainClass]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

so I explicitly point the configuration to the jar as advised in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files):

```
java -jar jarname.jar --spring.config.location=file:C:\path-to-build\config\application.properties
```

but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Try this; java -Dspring.config.location=/apps/xyzapp/properties/ -jar app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 0):

You should load it this way

```
java -jar jarname.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:file:///C:/directory/jdbc.properties
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the same issue though

Answer (score 0):

So it wasn't a problem with the command, my issue was that I had explicitly referenced the file in one of the Java classes:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```